# How to convert data:image/svg+xml;base64 data from natural image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, icons

I have a [blog](http://xameeramir.github.io/) in which I need to replace the `background-image` of `.svg-icon.googleplus` [(line 725 of the stylesheet)](http://xameeramir.github.io/style.css).

As of this point, it shows [Google+ icon](https://www.google.com/search?q=google+plus+icon). I need to replace it with [Google's original icon](https://pixabay.com/en/google-favicon-logo-icon-2015-1015752/). However I don't know how to convert the `data:image/svg+xml;base64` data from natural image.

Any suggestions, kind folks?

Comment: If I get the question correctly, there's no need to convert. Search for "google logo svg" and [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg) pops up. Make a data URL and you're done.

Comment: @LarsW - appreciate your inputs, but wanted to learn about converting images to `data:image/svg+xml;base64`? What is the method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any kind of image in the background url().
Does not need to be base64.
You could replace it with:

```
background-image: url('path/to/img/example.jpg');
background-image: url('path/to/img/example.gif');
background-image: url('path/to/img/example.png');
```

But if you still want to use Base64 you can use a program or a web service like this one:

https://www.base64-image.de/

Hope it helps